# Sql Pivot and Unpivot

Tags: sql, oracle

a newbie here..Actually I have a table in Oracle `vw_summary` as

```
Onum | Uacheck |  Uadesc  | AU11  |  AU12 | BD10  |
----------------------------------------------------------
 1   |   5.1   |  VENDOR  |  0    |   0   |    0  |

 2   |   5.2A  |  CUST    |  0    |   0   |    0  |
```

and I need data displayed as:-

```
Onum  |  PLant |   5.1 - VENDOR  |  5.2A - CUST
---------------------------------------------------

1     |   AU11   |   0             |   0

2     |   AU12   |   0             |   0

3     |   BD10   |   0             |   0
```

i.e. I need the columns `AU11, AU12, BD10` to become rows of my Plant column
and each concatenation of `UACHECK || UADESC` TO BECOME ROWS.

Comment: Don`t you mean 5.2A column?

Comment: yes..sorry..a typing mistake..can you help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH T1 AS (SELECT *
             FROM vw_summary UNPIVOT (plantvalue
                             FOR plant
                             IN (AU11, AU12, BD10))),
     T2
        AS (SELECT UACHECK,
                   UADESC,
                   PLANT,
                   PLANTVALUE,
                   ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY UADESC ORDER BY UADESC)
                      AS NUM
              FROM T1)
SELECT *
  FROM t2 PIVOT (MIN (PLANTVALUE)
          FOR (UADESC, UACHECK)
          IN  ( ('VENDOR', '5.1') AS "5.1 - VENDOR",
              ('CUST', '5.2A') AS "5.2A - CUST"));
```

Comment: I dun want to hardcode values..I want the values to be fetched from select query by concatenating uadesc || uacheck ..bcz i have way too many rows in the table..

Comment: Sorry, but you can not do dynamic `pivot` as in the case of `pivot xml`, at least in sql

Comment: we do not have any pl-sql concept where in some dynamic fetching is possible through variables? plus the above code is giving me "missing parentheses" error..I checked all the parentheses..where is the error I am not able to find out..

Comment: Uff, I don't know what is giving this error, i'm running on my toad sql editor an it's working fine

Comment: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 38 I thought its because of a line break or something..I wrote entire query..but again the same error